# MAP must be at least 'm x 3 array' error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dictionary, matlab-coder, imread

I am trying to generate C code with the *MATLAB Coder*. The input to the function is an image that has been processed by `imread` within MATLAB. Since the output should be an *m x n x 3* array from `imread`, I am not sure why this error is being shown. The assertions at the start of the function are shown below. Following that is the `rgb2gray` which is the source of the error.

```
%#codegen

assert(isa(IM, 'uint8'));
assert(size(IM, 1) < 100);
assert(size(IM, 2) < 100);
assert(size(IM, 3) == 3);

I_temp = rgb2gray(IM);
```

The error report I seem to be getting is shown below:

[image: Error Report]

The outputs and inputs to the function are given below:

```
function [actual_lep_x, actual_lep_y, actual_rep_x, actual_rep_y, actual_lmp_x, actual_lmp_y, actual_rmp_x, actual_rmp_y, actual_lnp_x, actual_lnp_y, np_x, np_y] = Points( IM )
```

I can send over the *.m* file if anyone needs to compile it.

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you kindly post the full error that you get into your question? Can we assume all the assertions are valid?

Comment: The second output argument of `imread` will give you the colormap (`m x 3`). First argument gives you the image itself (`m x 3` if grayscale, `m x n x 3` if color).

Comment: Does the colormap have to be the input to `rgb2gray`? Why can't the image itself be the input to `rgb2gray`? This [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) shows that it certainly can.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this using R2015a. Can you  post the entire function (part is cut off in the screenshot) and the codegen command being used?

Comment: I have edited the question to show the entirety of the function

Comment: Can you also show your Coder build script?  It may be a problem with specifying the arguments.  You can save a script from the Coder utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is *exactly* same as what you have shown in the image, then the error is obvious. `IM` seems to a filename, since on the line above, you have done `I_ttemp=imread(IM)` (which is commented for an unknown reason). Now, since `rgb2gray` did not receive an `m x n x 3` array, other argument it excepts is a colormap which has dimensions `m x 3`. However, you give a filename, which is of the form `1 x m`. Thus the error.

You should write:

```
I_temp=imread(IM);
if size(I_temp,3)==3
   I_temp=rgb2gray(I_temp);
end
%do processing on I_temp.
```

Comment: Since I am conerting the code from MATLAB to C, I cannot use `imread` within the function. However, I wanted the output of an `imread` I have written in a script to be the input to this function. I am currently asserting that `IM` is an image and not a filename. That is why I wasn't sure as to why I had this error.

Comment: I think the only reason for this error is that `IM` is not of the form `mxnx3`. However, if you are putting assertions for the same, it shouldn't be an issue. Can you see what kind of variable `IM` is? I haven't tried `codegen` but `whos` can tell you what kind of variable `IM` is.

Comment: `762x562x3 uint8`  is the answer I get when I run a valid input into the function and call whos